# Ubuntu can't find Scrapy

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I have Python 3.4 and Python2.7 installed. I installed scrapy using

```
sudo pip install scrapy
```

and if I try to rerun this, the terminal outputs :

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

But when I try to start a new project, I get this :

```
$ scrapy startproject tutorial
bash: /usr/local/bin/scrapy: No file or directory of this type
```

How should I change the path to Scrapy ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try to install it without `sudo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find where scrapy is installed

```
whereis scrapy
```

Then add that path to environment variable PATH

lets say its /usr/bin

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

Then you can call scrapy from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is too late. I faced this issue today and resolved it so I am adding answer so that it might help someone in future.

It happened because I installed scrapy as local user and not root. When you install it as user with `pip install scrapy --user` the scrapy script is not copied to `/usr/bin`. So in order to get it working you need to install it in one of the two ways:

1. Install as as root by using `sudo pip install scrapy`
2. Save this script somewhere in your home folder and run it whenever you ant to run scrapy(I have a ~/.scripts folder added to $PATH in which I store my scripts or just make an alias for the script )

```html
#!/usr/bin/python
   
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
if __name__ == '__main__':
  sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
  sys.exit(execute())
```

Answer (score 0):

The program installs into /usr/bin

Comment: I understand that, but then how do I execute the program ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were digging around in /usr/local/bin. I installed scrapy using synaptic and then ran the command that you provided: "scrapy startproject tutorial"  It worked a treat. The reason for installing using synaptic, is that you can ask for a packages properties and see what is included and where it has put them.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know about synaptic.